# Derivative of $\log|...|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me in this: I'm trying to find the derivative with respect to $x$, where $x$ is real, for the following function
$$\log\left|1-\frac{x}{w}\right|$$
where $w$ is a nonreal number (complex number)?

Answer (score 4):

Let $w=u+\imath\ v$, with $v\neq 0$.

Note that your $\log$ is the usual real logarithm, for its argument is a positive real number.
Hence, all you have to do is to compute the derivative (w.r.t. $x$ of course) of the real function:
$$f(x):=\log \sqrt{\frac{(u-x)^2+v^2}{u^2+v^2}} =\frac{1}{2}\ \log \Big( (u-x)^2+v^2\Big) - \frac{1}{2}\ \log \Big( u^2+v^2\Big)\; ,$$
which can be done using the usual *chain rule*.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\left| 1 - \frac{x}{w} \right| = \sqrt{ \left(1- \frac{x}{w} \right) \left(1- \frac{x}{w^*} \right) }.$$
Thus, we have  (as we take the derivative later, we do not have to worry about the branches) $$\log \left| 1 - \frac{x}{w} \right| = 
\frac12 \left[ \log\left(1- \frac{x}{w} \right) + \log\left(1- \frac{x}{w^*} \right) \right].  $$

Thus, the derivative is given by
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\log \left| 1 - \frac{x}{w} \right| = \frac{1}{2} \left[ 
\frac{w}{w-x} + \frac{w^*}{w^*-x} \right] = \frac{ \mathop{\rm Re} (w)  \,x - |w|^2}{ |w-x|^2}.$$